# SQL Stored procedures if statement inside select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

sorry if this will be a dumb question, it's first time i'm working with SQL stored procedures. The question is simple - how can I declare if statement inside SELECT? To show what I mean, here is a code I currently have:

```
INSERT INTO @trAll
SELECT tr.EventDateTime
    ,tr.OrderId
    ,'EX'
    ,round(tr.Prod01_CompB_QuantityPV_LTR + tr.Prod01_Fuel_QuantityPV_LTR,0)
    ,tr.eAD
    ,tr.OperatorName
    --
    ,cmr.ConsigneeName
    ,cmr.ConsigneeCompanyCode
    ,cmr.SenderName
    ,cmr.SenderCompanyCode
FROM vwTransaction AS tr
inner join tbOrderDetailCMR as cmr
on tr.orderid = cmr.OrderId
WHERE tr.EventDateTime BETWEEN @From
        AND @to
        AND ProductName = 'BIODIESELZ'
```

And this is what i need (hope you will understand what I mean):

```
INSERT INTO @trAll
SELECT tr.EventDateTime
    ,tr.OrderId
    ,'EX'
    ,round(tr.Prod01_CompB_QuantityPV_LTR + tr.Prod01_Fuel_QuantityPV_LTR+ (if (tr.Prod01_AdditiveA>0) THEN tr.Prod01_AdditiveA ELSE tr.Prod01_AdditiveB),0)
    ,tr.eAD
    ,tr.OperatorName
    --
    ,cmr.ConsigneeName
    ,cmr.ConsigneeCompanyCode
    ,cmr.SenderName
    ,cmr.SenderCompanyCode
FROM vwTransaction AS tr
inner join tbOrderDetailCMR as cmr
on tr.orderid = cmr.OrderId
WHERE tr.EventDateTime BETWEEN @From
        AND @to
        AND ProductName = 'BIODIESELZ'
```

In short what I need is to add AdditiveA if its value is bigger than 0, else AdditiveB inside select statement.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the syntax you're using I assume that this is T-SQL (Microsoft SQL-Server):

You can not use `IF` inside a statement like that. Use `CASE` here, like this:

```
...
,round(tr.Prod01_CompB_QuantityPV_LTR + tr.Prod01_Fuel_QuantityPV_LTR+ 
 (CASE 
     WHEN (tr.Prod01_AdditiveA>0) THEN tr.Prod01_AdditiveA 
     ELSE tr.Prod01_AdditiveB
 END),0) 
...
```

---

EDIT: In fact, now that I read it, Ashwin Nairs answer is even better. He uses the `IIF` command, which is less "intrusive". You might want to look at and/or accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using sql-server, try using `iif` instead

```
INSERT INTO @trAll
SELECT tr.EventDateTime
,tr.OrderId
,'EX'
,round(tr.Prod01_CompB_QuantityPV_LTR + tr.Prod01_Fuel_QuantityPV_LTR+ iif(tr.Prod01_AdditiveA>0, tr.Prod01_AdditiveA, tr.Prod01_AdditiveB),0)
,tr.eAD
,tr.OperatorName
--
,cmr.ConsigneeName
,cmr.ConsigneeCompanyCode
,cmr.SenderName
,cmr.SenderCompanyCode
FROM vwTransaction AS tr
inner join tbOrderDetailCMR as cmr
on tr.orderid = cmr.OrderId
WHERE tr.EventDateTime BETWEEN @From
    AND @to
    AND ProductName = 'BIODIESELZ'
```